# Shorten the easypagination page display length

Tags: jquery, css, html, pagination

I have a code were i used easypagination for pagination process but the issue which i am facing is, when the 'elementsPerPage' property is reduced to lesser number, the width of pagination increases but

i want it to be restricted with dot's in between like:
<< | < | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 8 | 9 | >>

Currently its like:
<< | < | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | >>

How can i achieve this in easypagination.?This could be great help.

Thank You,

My code goes here:

**.css**

```
 #easyPaginate {width:300px;}
 #easyPaginate img {display:block;margin-bottom:10px;}
.easyPaginateNav a {padding:5px;}
.easyPaginateNav a.current {font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;}
```

**.html**

```
<div id="easyPaginate">
    <img src="img/demo/surf1.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf2.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf3.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf4.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf5.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf6.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf7.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf8.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf9.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf10.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf11.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf12.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf13.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf14.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf15.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf16.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf17.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf18.jpg" />
</div>
```

**.js**

```
$('#easyPaginate').easyPaginate({
    paginateElement: 'img',
    elementsPerPage: 3,
    effect: 'climb'
});
```

Comment: which pagination library you've used, googling "easypagination" shows multiple results. it would be helpful if you give the library link in your question.

Comment: @AminurRashid Here is the link:http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/

Comment: looks like this library doesn't have the option of showing limited numbers in pagination. can you use another library which has this functionality built-in, rather than implementing on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old plugin (by Tue, 22 Oct 2013)
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/User-Friendly-Pagination-Plugin-With-jQuery-Bootstrap-easyPaginate/

Comment: I have been through them, they give no proper code description on how to integrate with simple code...given in bits and pieces...but any how thanks for the responce..!